# determining if a cell is occupied in a gridbag layout

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have a n number of components in a grid bag layout. These components can have a gridwidth and gridheight of 1 or more. there can be n number of rows but only 2 components at most per row.

is there anyway to check if a gridbag cell is occupied already. So if component 'A' has a height of 2 and is in cell 0x0, I can find if 0x1 is occupied and skip placing a component there?

I thought about a `boolean[][]` array but the max rows and columns can change depending on the layout (the user can move the components up and down, remove them, and add them).

another note the components get added as 
0x0 -> 0x1 
1x0 -> 1x1

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I ended up solvong this my making an `ArrayList` of `Boolean[]`s. In my instance i knew there would only be 2 columns. If you are unsure you may want to do a 2d ArrayList.

```
private void updateTableLayout() {
        //tableHolderPanel holds the JXTitledPanels
        GridBagLayout gbl = (GridBagLayout) tableHolderPanel.getLayout();
        List<Boolean[]> occupied = new ArrayList<Boolean[]>();
        occupied.add(new Boolean[]{false, false});
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        boolean notPlaced;
        for (TableJXPanel table : tableList) {
            GridBagConstraints gbc = gbl.getConstraints(table);
            notPlaced = true;

            while (notPlaced) {
                if (!occupied.get(y)[x]) {
                    //Set true to first cell occupied
                    occupied.get(y)[x] = true;
                    if (gbc.gridwidth > 1 && x == 0) {
                        occupied.get(y)[1] = true;
                    }

                    //Add any additional cells and set them.
                    for (int i = 0; i < gbc.gridheight - 1; i++) {
                        if (gbc.gridwidth > 1) {
                            occupied.add(new Boolean[]{true, true});
                        } else {
                            occupied.add(new Boolean[]{false, false});
                            occupied.get(y+1)[x] = true;
                        }
                    }
                    //Add new row for next comparison
                    if(occupied.get(y)[1])
                        occupied.add(new Boolean[]{false, false});

                    //signal that the table was placed
                    notPlaced = false;
                    gbc.gridy = y;
                    gbc.gridx = x;
                }
                if (x == 0) {
                    x++;
                } else {
                    x = 0;
                    y++;
                }
            }
            tableHolderPanel.remove(table);
            tableHolderPanel.add(table, gbc);
        }
    }
```

This may not be the best code so if anyone sees something that should be changed just leave a comment.